# Why Fourier sine series span $L^2(0,L)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_sine_and_cosine_series) is the definition of the Fourier sine series $\{\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L},\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

What I want to show is :

> For $f\in L^{2}(0,L)$, if $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\int_{0}^{L}f(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L} dx=0,$$
>    then $f=0$ a.e.

Any suggestion about this?

(Trial) Let us suppose not. I suppose $f>0$ on a finite positive measurable set $A\subset (0,L)$. Is it okay if I assume this?

Comment: Do you know the fact that continuous functions are dense in $L^2$?  Do you know the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: @NateEldredge I know those fact and theorem. Then how could I use them here?